Hover function not working on elementor pop up
I'm currently working on an Elementor project that has a pop up menu, and I'm hoping to establish a widget of Interactive Links (it shows a list of elements and when you hover on each one of them, an image appears).
The issue I'm having is that the on hover function works fine when I preview just the popup, but when I try to view it as a popup on the main page, the function stops working.
I've tried with the widget and replicating the widget with html, css and js. Neither of them worked out, so I figured out the problem is on the hover function inside the pop up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
